# Generate Unique ID from User details

Tags: android, biometrics, unique-id

> My scenario is almost same as Aadhaar doing to generate UID.

I need to generate unique id for each user from user details while user are enrolling from multiple device or multiple user from single device

I have following detail of user

1. First Name
2. Last name
3. DOB Biometric data (2 to 5 Fingers)

From this detail i need to fetch out a unique id for each user.

**????-????-????**

> I tried many methods like get hashmap from each string but i want 0
>   probability of having duplicate id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with hashset instead of hashmap.

Comment: Chances of duplicate ids from multiple device,,

Answer (score 0):

Can the unique id contain a set of numbers along with those details?

If Yes :  then simply concatenate a series of numbers with subStrings of first name ,last name and biometric data.

If No : Create the unique id and compare it with a Collection  of already generated id's. If the Collection contains the id then change the amount of concatenation you are doing.

Comment: in your both steps there is huge possibility of having duplicate ids.

Comment: Lets assume we have ten people with the same first name, last name and even biometric data. First Name:David Last Name:Gilmour. Now 1st person will have unique id 001davgil , 2nd person 002davgil and so on.Agree? And for the second case lets say you have stored unique id as davgil. Put that in a List or a Map. Now when the second david gilmour comes you change the substring parameter from 3 to 4 .Now unique id will be davegil